# Add packade weight to WooCommerce order/cart

Tags: woocommerce

Been searhing for a simple way to add 400 g to all orders for the shipping plugin to get the correct weight. Looked at [Cart total Weight and Shipping Recalculation on WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410653/cart-total-weight-and-shipping-recalculation-on-woocommerce) but do not need all that

Comment: @Barnabas any tip?

Comment: `@` tags don't work unless the person has already interacted with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change your Weight Unit first in **WooCommerce > Settings > Product > Measurements** section.

[image: WooCommerce > Settings > Product > Measurements section]

Then use the following filter hook in your functions.php to override the total cart weight.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_weight','add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight');

function add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {        
    $weight = 400; // change to your expected cart content weight.      
    return $weight;     
}
```

Please note that it's recommended to use a child while you add custom codes to your theme.

Comment: Thanks. I added it as a snippet but it returner an error

syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: @AndreasDamberg It should work fine. Can you share a screenshot of where you added it and where it shows up the error?

Comment: @AbdullahAlFaruk You are missing a semicolon in the first line of your function.

Comment: Ops! I am really sorry. Thanks a lot @Terminator-Barbapapa

Comment: @AndreasDamberg I have corrected it. Try now

Comment: @AbdullahAlFaruk Thanks! It worked but changes the total weight to 400g. I would like it to take the original weight of all products in cart and then add 400 g. I have a shipping plugin that forwards the total weight so for that to be correct it needs the total shipment weight and not just product weight as now.

Or could you make it add different weights depending on the total weight? If total weight is below or exatly 600 g, add 200g. Above 600g add 400 g?

Comment: A managed to add 400 g by adding +=, instead of only =

Comment: As I need to add weight to the order I changed the code and added +=. I also added an if to check the weight and adding different package weights depending on the cart weight. It works but I don't know if I missed something or can do it in a better way? I used the https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-cart-weight/] to see the cart weight at cart and checkout page

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_weight','add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight');
    
    function add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {        
     
     if ($weight <= 600) {
      $weight += 200;
      return $weight;
     } 

     elseif ($weight > 600) {
        $weight += 400;
     return $weight;
     } 
    }

Comment: You have the correct solution in your last comment. If you have got your answer please mark it as accepted. Thank you